# What is the density profile of Sagittarius A*'s accretion disk?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, accretion-disk

It is thought that Sagittarius A*, the [supermassive black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*) at the center of the Milky Way, is surrounded by an [accretion disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk).

Can anyone provide a resource for the general density profile of this disk? I'm interested in general characteristic features e.g. maximum density, $r$ dependence etc.